# UIView frame issue

Tags: ios, view, frame

I am having a weird problem. I have two view controllers. A homeViewController and a settingViewController.

homeViewController has no navigation bar while the settingViewController has.

Now the issue is when i push settingViewController and get back from it my homeViewController view's height gets small. (view's height - navigation bar height)

(don't want to adjust frame manually)

```
// homeViewController
-(void) settingButtonPressed {

    SettingsViewController *svc = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
}

// settingViewController
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;

    UIInterfaceOrientation statusBarOrientation =[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:statusBarOrientation duration:0.0];
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

Please suggest the work around for it.

Comment: try  to put your code, it will easy to solve your problem.

Comment: Show us the code what you wrote in ViewDidLoad Or ViewWillAppear:

Comment: Nothing is happening related to navigation on viewDidLoad. viewDidLoad   will be called once and it just adjust the view ok of both the controllers.

Comment: put u r homeview viewdidload and viewwill appear methods.

Answer (score 0):

Write in **homeVC.m**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

And in **settingVC.m**

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated];   

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: i am doing the same. The issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to govern the visibility of the navigation bar in view will appear and will disappear for the individual view controllers, try governing it in the navigation controller's delegate.

Answer (score 0):

try to  settingViewController 's  pop action method

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```