# UIView Frame Changes on dissmissviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiview, delegates, uitableview, presentviewcontroller

I have `UIVIewController` & `UITableViewContoller` in my project.I am presenting `UITableViewController` on `UIButton` action in first `UIVIewController` and select data from tableview to display in my First `UIVIewController` using `Protocol` Method.

```
 tableViewController *objPlanTable = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"presentTableView"];
    objPlanTable.myDelegate = self;
    objPlanTable.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

    [self presentViewController:objPlanTable animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This is my `UITableViewDelegate` Method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *aCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if([self.myDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(selectPlan:)])
    {
        [self.myDelegate selectPlan:aCell.textLabel.text];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];


    }
    if ([self.myDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)])
    {
        [self.myDelegate backgroundChanger];
    }

}
```

But on Completion it changes my **`UIVIew`** Height which contains UIButton. This `UIVIew` is `UIViewController`>>`UIView`>>`UIScrollView`>>**`UIView`**

How do i keep my this UIView as it is before `UITableViewController` presented;

I found similar question on **StackOverFlow** [UIView Frame Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779128/uiview-frame-issue),but it is for push `UIVIewContoller` & did not helped.

Please Correct me if i am doing anything wrong,Any Idea/Help will be appreciated.

Comment: New Changes       

-(void)selectPlan:(NSString*)strPlanName      

Added     

-(void)selectPlan:(NSString*)strPlanName :(int)interfaceFlag;     

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated      
{
    if (final == 1)
    {
       my original frame.
    }
}


But Still it Reflects after one second delay which is not good for ui. any idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done, set my ui to original state before `UIViewController` presented on protocol Method.

Alternate is to Push rather than Present `UIViewController`.